# Svg Закругленные уголки

Tags: html, css, svg

Вообщем у меня есть код SVG закругленных уголков.

Как равномерно залить каждый треугольник ,чтобы вышел полный круг?

[>>>>> DEMO <<<<<](http://jsfiddle.net/f88ok31w/)

```
        <svg version="1.1" id="smart_circle" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 314.5 313.8" enable-background="new 0 0 314.5 313.8" xml:space="preserve" onmousedown="return false">
            <a xlink:href="javascript:void(0);" id="segment1">
                <path fill="#9139b2" d="M157.2,156.9V0.3c34.6,0,64.1,9.6,92.1,29.9L157.2,156.9z"/>
            </a>
            <a xlink:href="javascript:void(0);" id="segment8">
                <path fill="#00a0e3" d="M157.2,156.9l-149,48.4c-10.7-32.9-10.7-63.9,0-96.8L157.2,156.9z"/>
            </a>
            <a xlink:href="javascript:void(0);" id="segment7">
                <path fill="#dc4437" d="M157.2,156.9L65.2,283.6c-28-20.3-46.2-45.4-56.9-78.3L157.2,156.9z"/>
            </a>
            <a xlink:href="javascript:void(0);" id="segment6">
                <path fill="#00be9c" d="M157.2,156.9v156.6c-34.6,0-64.1-9.6-92.1-29.9L157.2,156.9z"/>
            </a>
            <a xlink:href="javascript:void(0);" id="segment5">
                <path fill="#64b044" d="M157.2,156.9l92.1,126.7c-28,20.3-57.5,29.9-92.1,29.9V156.9z"/>
            </a>
            <a xlink:href="javascript:void(0);" id="segment4">
                <path fill="#0032ff" d="M157.2,156.9l149,48.4c-10.7,32.9-28.9,58-56.9,78.3L157.2,156.9z"/>
            </a>
            <a xlink:href="javascript:void(0);" id="segment3">
                <path fill="#f1e411" d="M157.2,156.9l149-48.4c10.7,32.9,10.7,63.9,0,96.8L157.2,156.9z"/>
            </a>
            <a xlink:href="javascript:void(0);" id="segment2">
                <path fill="#ee7121" d="M157.2,156.9l92.1-126.7c28,20.3,46.2,45.4,56.9,78.3L157.2,156.9z"/>
            </a>
        </svg>v
```

Comment: Закругленные уголки? Где?

Comment: о чем вы? Демо на jsfiddle указано же

Comment: В смысле, как поменять код, чтобы каждый сектор был на 1/8 оборота, а не на 1/10 как сейчас?

Comment: https://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/creating-a-svg-pie-chart-html5/

Comment: во! Очень хорошая статья! спасибо!